# Graphing an N-channel MOSFET's characteristic curve in LTSpice: Am I doing it wrong?

Tags: mosfet, ltspice, spice

I was trying to replicate the characteristic curve of an N-channel MOSFET in LTSpice. I wanted to achieve something like this:

[image: NChannel]

but I end up getting this graph instead:

[image: The drain current Id is in the negatives]

in which the drain current are in the negatives. I am not really that familiar with SPICE syntax so pointing out where I did get it wrong would be a great help.

The SPICE Directive I've constructed:

```
MOS   100 1 0 0 MOS
Vbias 1 0 DC 1.5
Vd    110 0 DC 1.5
Vid   110 100 DC 0
 
.MODEL MOS NMOS
 
.DC Vd 0 12 .0001 Vbias 0 5 1
.PROBE          DC I(Vd)
*.PRINT DC  V(1,XIS.2) V(XIS.2,0) V(XIS.23) V(XIS.46) V(1)I(Vid)
.OP
.END
```

Was it the circuit I've constructed, or was it my syntax/semantics that was wrong? I was pretty sure I used an N-type enhancement mode MOSFET.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Component in SPICE, even symmetrical ones like resistors, have pre-assigned current polarity when measuring current through them.

If you are measuring current through the voltage source it is negative via passive sign  convention. If you want it to read positive you will need to add in a current sense resistor and position it the correct way and read the current through that.

Answer (score 1):

Realized I connected a voltage source (Vd) instead of a load resistor. Every dog has its dumb day.

Comment: It happens, but it might happen less if you used the graphical schematic editor. :-) (also, you can select DKNguyen's answer if it solves your problem)

Comment: The source material from which I've acquired the directive had a voltage source in place of a resistor. I'm figuring out why was it constructed as such.

Comment: Maybe there was a voltage source, too, in series? If not, it's possible you haven't found a very reliable source.

Answer (score 0):

You can right-click on the trace title and add a minus sign in front of I(Vd) where it says "Enter an algebraic equation to plot".

Comment: He could, but he'd only get positive `uA`. :-)

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen True. Just addressing the polarity issue.